# How to write for loop for console log of web browser

Tags: javascript, java, automation, console, web-console

I am currently learning some Automation.

I just wanted to know how to we write a `for` loop for a button in the webpage with the help of browser console.

```
document.querySelector('.glyphsSpriteCircle_add__outline__24__grey_9').click()
```

I need to this button to clicked until the button element is present.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You mean the user has to spam click this button until another button is present? o.0 Or did I get it wrong (like I assume)

Comment: @monamona, Yes it has to run in a loop until the button is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You continuously invoke a function with `setTimeout` until the element is found.

```
function searchAndClick(selector, delay = 250){
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(el != null){
        el.click();
    } else {
        setTimeout(()=>searchAndClick(selector,delay),delay);
    }
}
searchAndClick('.glyphsSpriteCircle_add__outline__24__grey_9');
```